# Concatenating Dynamic SQL commands with UNION returns inconsistent results

Tags: sql-server

I'm testing a report that I've written in T-SQL and I'm having some issues with the results that are being returned. Here is the section of the code that I'm having issues with;

```
CREATE TABLE #Tables
    (   ID      INT IDENTITY (1,1),
        TenantId        nvarchar(10),
        TaskTable   nvarchar(50),
        RecordTable nvarchar(50),   
        RecordColumn    nvarchar(50)    )

SELECT @TSQL AS SQLCommand
    INTO #Commands

INSERT INTO #Tables
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) as TenantId, 
                t.[name] TaskTable,
                t2.[name] RecordTable,
                c.[name] RecordColumn
    from sys.tables t, sys.tables t2
    join sys.columns c on t2.object_id = c.object_id
    where t.[name] in ('Task', 'Tasks')
    and t2.[name] in ('TimeRecord', 'TimeRecords')
    and schema_name(t.schema_id) >= 50
    and schema_name(t.schema_id) <> 275     -- Exclude this because it's missing tables
    and c.[name] like 'FK_Task%'
    group by (schema_name(t.schema_id)), t.[name], t2.[name], c.[name]

        union 

    select schema_name(t.schema_id) as TenantId, 
                t.[name] TaskTable,
                t2.[name] RecordTable,
                c.[name] RecordColumn
    from sys.tables t, sys.tables t2
    join sys.columns c on t2.object_id = c.object_id
    where t.[name] in ('Tasks_NEW', 'Task_NEW')
    and t2.[name] in ('TimeRecord_NEW', 'TimeRecords_NEW')
    and schema_name(t.schema_id) >= 50
    and c.[name] like 'FK_Task%'
    group by (schema_name(t.schema_id)), t.[name], t2.[name], c.[name]

        union

    select schema_name(t.schema_id) as TenantId, 
                t.[name] TaskTable,
                t2.[name] RecordTable,
                c.[name] RecordColumn
    from sys.tables t, sys.tables t2
    join sys.columns c on t2.object_id = c.object_id
    where t.[name] in ('Tasks_WOM', 'Task_WOM')
    and t2.[name] in ('TimeRecord_WOM', 'TimeRecords_WOM')
    and schema_name(t.schema_id) >= 50
    and c.[name] like 'FK_Task%'
    group by (schema_name(t.schema_id)), t.[name], t2.[name], c.[name]


SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #Tables)
SET @Iter = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM #Tables)

WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
BEGIN
     SELECT @TenantId = TenantId, @TaskTable = TaskTable, @RecordTable = RecordTable, @RecordColumn = RecordColumn
        FROM #Tables
             WHERE id = @Iter

SET @TSQL =     N'SELECT '+@TenantId+' AS TenantId, COUNT(*) AS IntegrationDates, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Dynamic].['+@TenantId+'].['+@TaskTable+']  WHERE SystemId NOT IN (SELECT '+@RecordColumn+' FROM [Dynamic].['+@TenantId+'].['+@RecordTable+'])) AS MissingTimeRecords FROM [Dynamic].['+@TenantId+'].['+@TaskTable+']  WHERE IntegrationDate IS NULL'

INSERT INTO #Commands
SELECT @TSQL AS SQLCommand  

SET @Iter = @Iter + 1

END

SELECT @TSQLFinal = IsNull(@TSQLFinal + '
UNION 
', '' ) + SQLCommand
FROM #Commands

CREATE TABLE #Results   (   ApplicationId INT,
                                                IntegrationDates INT,
                                                MissingTimeRecords INT)
INSERT INTO #results
EXEC (@TSQLFinal)
```

If I `SELECT * FROM #Commands` I get to see all of the commands built by my Dynamic Statement, which is 275 rows in this case.

This is perfect, but if I then `SELECT * FROM #results` I do not get 275 rows. I sometimes get 30 rows, sometimes 100, but it's never consistent.

What I'm expecting here, is that all of my commands in the #Commands temp table, get executed and the results of these commands are put into the #results table (hence the UNION)

Can anything spot what might be going wrong here at all?

Thanks in advance!

Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [EzLo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/147776/ezlo) said: Don't use variable assignment through `SELECT` to aggregate values. You do this when setting `@TSQLFinal`. Try with `STRING_AGG()` if you have SQL Server 2017+ or `FOR XML PATH('')` on lower versions.

Comment: Implemented the STRING_AGG() method into the script and now I seem to be finally getting consistent results. "SET @TSQLFinal =(SELECT STRING_AGG(SQLCommand, ' union ') FROM #Commands)"

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't show where `@TSQLFinal` is declared.  Make sure that it's a large enough data type to hold all your results.

Also, `UNION` suppresses duplicate results by default.  If you want all the results, use `UNION ALL`.